# Rotate button on center axis

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have written the following code to rotate a tab bar button.  But it looks like it rotates the button on the bottom left axis which causes the button to move slightly to the right.

How can I make it rotate on the center axis?

```
private func rotateCenterButton(reverse: Bool = false)
{
    if let item = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[2],
       let view = item.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: reverse ? CGFloat(0) : CGFloat.pi / 4)
        })
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Solved mt issues like this:

```
private func rotateCenterButton(reverse: Bool = false)
{
    if let item = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[2],
       let view = item.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
    {
        let bt = view.subviews.first
        bt!.contentMode = .center
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations:{
            bt!.transform = reverse ? .identity : CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/4)
        })
    }
}
```